# program terminates on Index out-of-range

Tags: c++, string

I have to write a program that accepts string input and outputs sorted string without special characters but it throws an index out of bounds exception even when the loops run only till the end of the string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string mes="";
    string tem;
    cin>>tem;
    for (int i=0;i<tem.length();i++){
        char ch=tem.at(i);
        if((ch<=65&&ch<=90)||(ch>=97&&ch<=122))
            mes+=ch;
        else
            continue;
    }
    cout<<mes;
    for(int i=0;i<tem.length();i++){
        int small=(int)mes.at(i);
        int spos=i;
        for(int j=i;j<tem.length();j++){
            int a=(int)mes.at(j);
            if(a<small){
                small=a;
                spos=j;
            }
        }
        char temp=' ';
        temp=mes.at(i);
        mes.at(i)=mes.at(spos);
        mes.at(spos)=temp;
    }
    cout<<mes;
}
```

Here is the error message:

> terminate 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string::at: __n (which is 3) >= this->size() (which is 3)

Comment: You should probably use `mes.length()` in the loops reading from `mes`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<tem.length();i++){
    int small=(int)mes.at(i);
```

You iterate over indexes of `tem`, but read `mes` whose size is different.

Comment: Note: your program could be improuved on _many_ levels: write small functions, use the tools from `std::` (especially `<algorithm>`), avoid superfluous code (life `else continue`), ...

Answer (score 0):

You may need to correct first

```
if((ch<=65&&ch<=90)||(ch>=97&&ch<=122))

to

if(( ch >= 65 && ch <= 90) || ( ch >= 97 && ch <= 122))
```

Second:
The size of the second string (`mes`) will always going to be less than the size of the first string (`tem`). But in your second loop, you used `i` to navigate through the second string (`mes`), which causes the `out of range` exception.